# Multiple sandbox URL configuration in wso2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, endpoints

I am looking for configuring multiple sandbox URL in wso2 API manager as the API which i am configuring is deployed in various lower environment(like Dev,Test,UAT).

Is it possible is wso2 api manager if yes, what configuration needs to be changed to get above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Add any number of environments at the api-manager.xml under `Apigateway` section

```
  <APIGateway>
        <Environments>
............
    </Environments>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

I guess your expectation is to have different live cycles on DEV, QA, UAT and PROD environments. And this cannot be achieved with the current version 1.8.0 of API manager (out of the box). At least this is the information we got from WSO2 through their official consulting partner Yenlo.

After my first answer I found also this [link](https://denuwanthi.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/wso2-apim-deploy-apim-artifacts-to-multiple-environments-devqa-prod/) which has more details on staging APIs with WSO2 API manager.